# Is it ever necessary to end a (perl) Moose class with 1;?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm new to Moose, and by the [Moose manual on classes](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.0802/lib/Moose/Manual/Classes.pod) it seems that a valid class is:

```perl
package Person;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Moose;

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

But where is the terminal "I'm returning true" `1;` ???

I can find many example of Moose classes that *do* end with `1;` but is this useless or is it sometimes necessary (and why)? Since I can also find many examples of Moose classes with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`, which are definitely redundant, it seems that some old perl habits die hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `$meta->make_immutable` is guaranteed to return a true value.

> This method will create an immutable transformer and use it to make the class and its metaclass object immutable, **and returns true** (you should not rely on the details of this value apart from its truth).

Comment: I assume that applies to `no moose;` as well?

Comment: No, `no moose;` does not result in any code. It means `BEGIN { require moose; moose->unimport; }`

Comment: So there is nothing special about Moose class modules in this regard? I can see that the normal structure tends to result in such a thing happening without doing it explicitly but a terminal true returning statement is still needed? If this isn't "guaranteed" then a terminal `1;` ensuring this return state seems like a reasonable thing.

Comment: Yes, they still need to return true. You can test this by placing a `0;` at the end.